# ping between client to client not working

Tags: 16.04, vpn, openvpn, ping

setup Openvpn

Server ip 192.168.70.22 tun0 - 10.8.0.1

Client1 ip 192.168.1.3 tun0 - 10.8.0.6

Client2 ip 192.168.30.44 tun0 - 10.8.0.10

ping tun0 works

ping server from client1 and client2 works vice versa

also IP address
ping server ip from client1 and client2 works

But

ping client1 from client2 and server not working

ping client2 from client1 and server not working

Comment: Does server have ipv4 forwarding on? Do clients know routes to other clients?

Comment: yes, ipv4 forwarding is enabled.

Comment: And what is the answer for the second question of mine?

Comment: I didn't done the second one

Answer (score 1):

```
The result of route -n (**server**)
Kernel IP routing table  
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  
0.0.0.0         192.168.5.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0  
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0  
10.15.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0  
192.168.1.0     10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0  
192.168.2.0     10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0  
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0  
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0   
192.168.5.66    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0  

The result of route -n (**client1**)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s3
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     10.8.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s3
192.168.5.0     10.8.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.5.66    192.168.2.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp0s3

The result of route -n (**client2**)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlp4s0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     10.8.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlp4s0
192.168.2.0     10.8.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.5.0     10.8.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.5.66    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp4s0
```

Comment: And the second client?

Comment: The second client in above answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already enabled ipv4 forwarding, you have also:

1. Inform your clients that VPN server is also a gateway to other VPN clients. You can achieve this by adding this line to your server configuration file:

`push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"`

2. Check if your firewall on VPN server allows forwarding packets:

`sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT`

If you can't ping clients from VPN server, maybe your clients just do not answer for pings? What os is on your clients?

Comment: ping 10.8.0.4
PING 10.8.0.4 (10.8.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.0.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=65.3 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=87.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=44.2 ms

Comment: Could you please describe your comment? It doesn't tell much if you just paste result of some command.

Comment: **1**. Both clients and server are ubuntu 16.04

**2**. Ping from server using tun0 is working 

**ping client-1 from server (10.8.0.1)**
user@server:~$ ping 10.8.0.4
PING 10.8.0.4 (10.8.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.0.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=65.3 ms
^C

**ping client-2 from server (10.8.0.1)**
user@server:~$ ping 10.8.0.8
PING 10.8.0.8 (10.8.0.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.0.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=39.8 ms
^C

Comment: **3**.but using eth0 not working    
**ping client-1 from server (192.168.5.66)    **
user@server:~$ ping 192.168.1.4    
PING 192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4) 56(84) bytes of data.    
^C     

**ping client-2 from server (192.168.5.66)     **
user@server:~$ ping 192.168.2.100     
PING 192.168.2.100 (192.168.2.100) 56(84) bytes of data.    
^C

Comment: Paste result of command `route -n` from both clients into the text of your question (not in comment).

Comment: route -n added in answer